# Can you view a shared iTunes 11 library from iTunes 7, or use iMac as an Airplay target?

Tags: itunes, imac, airplay

I picked up a beautiful old G3 Tangerine iMac.  Works (and looks!) great.

It has iTunes 7 installed on it.  I popped a music CD in it and it's a great little music player for my den -- sounds surprisingly good.

What I'd like to do now is one of two things:

1 - share my iTunes 11 library (from my MacBook) and play songs from the shared library on iTunes 7 on the G3 iMac

2 - or even better, use the G3 iMac as a sort of "Airplay" target, make song selections in iTunes 11 on my MacBook and have the music play on the G3 iMac

Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: What OS is the G3 running?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.4 ...

Answer (score 1):

Install Airfoil Speakers on the G3.  They have a legacy version that runs on 10.4.

http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php

> Run it on any Mac and it will immediately be able to receive audio.
>   Airfoil Speakers for Mac receives audio from Airfoil for Mac and
>   Airfoil for Windows, as well as iTunes, iOS devices, and other
>   third-party software. See it in action.